# Accuracy of Math.sin() in Java for common angles

Tags: java, performance, double, precision, floating-accuracy

I've got two methods calculating the derivative of sin(pi), it's for uni - one uses the common numerical differentiation formula, the other I rewrote as follows:

```
// h = 1e−16 (part of assignment)
// f'(x) ~= (f(x+h)-f(x))/h  for sin(x)
public static double differentiateSin(double x) {
    return (Math.sin(x+h)-Math.sin(x))/h;
}

// using trigonometry
public static double differentiateSin2(double x) {
    return (2* ( Math.sin(h/2) * Math.cos(x+h/2) ) )  /h;
}
```

I'm aware that floating point numbers cannot be represented exactly, much less pi, what surprises me is that I'm getting quite an exact result with the second method, while the first is completely off track!

Math(cos(Math.pi)) gives an exact -1.0, I guess that's okay, it's a common angle - but I can't figure out what makes such a difference between these methods. There's more operations, I didn't get rid of sin and cos, and yet I'm getting perfect results.

Also making 'h' bigger gives more reasonable results... What happens there?

Comment: *"I'm aware that floating point numbers cannot be represented exactly..."* Right. And so since your series of operations is different, clearly that lack of precision matters for some intermediate value in one case.

Comment: Naturally, a bigger `h` will give you a more accurate result.  Once `h` gets close to the size of the difference between consecutive `double` values, the floating point inaccuracies start eating into the ratio that you're trying to measure.